# share buttons count not working on dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, ajax, share, sharethis

I am using ajax to load a new page but it is only displaying the share buttons and not displaying the share count.

```js
$("body a").click(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml"
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (typeof(history.pushState) != "undefined") {
      var obj = {
        Title: title,
        Url: url
      };
      history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } else {
      alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }

    var $divToFind = $($.parseHTML(jqXHR.responseText)).filter("#radio-main-wrapper");
    $('#radio-main-wrapper').html($($divToFind).html());
    $.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js");
    stButtons.locateElements();
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  });
});
```

Comment: This comment is not relevant to the problem but a pointer to your other mistake in the code`$.getScript("http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js");` this will load the same script as many times as the `a` is clicked, which causes you problem.

Comment: @Reddy Thanks I will change that.

Comment: Can you also post your response html?

Answer (score 0):

Try using easyshare plugin --

https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.easyshare

Simple to use and This will solve your ajax problem.